# How can I add a link to an image opened in a lightbox leading to external ".html"?

Tags: javascript, css, html, lightbox

I have a gallery in which the images that are clicked open in a lightbox. I want to add the option that the OPENED image can then be clicked again to link to an external page.

I already tried to wrap the  tag in another  tag  - what was of course not successful - and was looking for some "data" code to add to the "href" line... but found nothing so far. Here is the code:

```
<div class="homepage-portfolio-preview-1 new-animation">
  <a class="lightbox"href="img/Portfolio_img/Ele_macs.jpg">
    <span class="background full-size" style="background-image: url(img/Portfolio_img/Ele_macs_thumb.jpg);"></span>
    <span class="text">
      <span class="h4 light"><b>WEBSEITEN LAYOUT</b></span>
      <span class="empty-space col-xs-b15"></span>
      <span class="simple-article large light transparent">TK Elementa</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want the image link to the page where the project is described in detail BUT also want the viewer to be able to see the zoomed version of the image... Hoping for some help. Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what kind of help you exactly need? in brief?

Comment: Have you tried to use javascript with onclick event, then when the lightbox has showed up you bind the event to the tag you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the link tag inside the span?

```
<span class="background full-size" style="background-image: url(img/Portfolio_img/Ele_macs_thumb.jpg);">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
</span>
```